# IPython Notebook Error

Tags: ubuntu, jupyter-notebook

I am getting the following error when trying to run IPython Notebook:

> [2071:2098:0402/080647:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(624)] Failed to get name owner. Got org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get owner of name 'org.chromium.Mtpd': no such name

And am not able to open a notebook.

Anyone have any ideas?